# store double quotes inside single quotes

Tags: c#

I want to store inside char array some characters, one of them is double quotes("). I tried with escape characters, but I'm doing something wrong.

```
private char[] characters = new char[] { '\"\"', ... };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `char` type can only store a single character, you're trying to store two double quotes. Try this:

```
private char[] characters = new char[] { '"', ... };
```

You are also trying to escape it but it's unnecessary. Escaping double quote is only required if you're inside a string literal, ie. inside double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

A char is exactly one character. You are trying to put two into it. Put only one into it.
Furthermore, because a char is designated by single quotes, you don't need to escape the double quotes - but doing so isn't an error and will work, too.
So, either one of the following is correct:

```
private char[] characters = new char[] { '"', ... };
private char[] characters = new char[] { '\"', ... };
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `{ '"', ... };` Like;

```
private char[] characters = new char[] { '"', ... };
```

As other said, [`char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx) type contains one unicode character. You don't have to use escape characters for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
private char[] characters = new char[] { '\"','\"', ... };
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is correct. You *can* escape a double quote inside a char.